# Mongoose query that limit the collections to collections those belong to the logged in user or that logged in user is allowed to see

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt, authorization

I am working on a web app, where every user should see their own collections. So if i log in as user1, it should show user1's collections and if i log in as user2 it should show only user2's collections.

Right now, no matter which user i log in, and get collections route  it does show all collections. I am using expressjs and mongoose.I need help how to query from db to get specific data which is belong to logged in user

**Collections route**

```
collectionRouter.get("/", async(req,res,next)=> {
    try {   
        const collections= await CollectionModel.find()
        res.send(collections)
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})

collectionRouter.post("/", async(req,res,next)=> {
    try {
        const collection = new CollectionModel(req.body)
        const {_id} = await collection.save()
        res.status(201).send({_id})
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})
```

**User login route**

```
userRouter.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!(email && password))
      res.status(204).send({ msg: "All fields are required!" });
    const user = await UsersModel.checkCredentials(email, password);
    if (user) {
      const accessToken = await JWTAuthenticate(user);
      res.status(200).send({ accessToken });
    } else {
      next(
        createHttpError(401, "Credentials are not ok. User does not exist!")
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

**Collections schema**

```
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const collectionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    topic: { type: String },
    comments: [
      {
        commentArea: { type: String, required: true },
        commentedDate: `enter code here`{ type: Date },
      },
    ],
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    likes:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Like"}],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
export default model("Collection", collectionSchema);
```

Comment: I'm sure you must realize that you have to use database queries that limit the results to results that belong to the logged in user or that the logged in user is allowed to see.  Right now, you're doing generic queries that aren't limited to any particular user so every user see everything.

Comment: i was generating accesstoken for every logged in user and getting collecttions by token but still giving all collections. ca u help me how to query from db in get collections route?

Comment: Well, you don't show any code that attempts to make the queries apply only to one user's data.  You are more likely  to attract help from someone who knows mongoose queries if you show the code you tried and explain what results you got. I'm not a mongoose person so that will have to be someone else, but if you fix your question, you can make it more likely someone follows what you're trying to do and can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to protect the endpoint so you can get the logged in `user` id. Then, you will have to query `collections` by current logged in user's `_id` to get specific data related to the user.

Example usage of an auth middleware:

```js
collectionRouter.get("/", yourAuthMiddleware(), async(req,res,next)=> {
    try {   
        // method to obtain user id will depend on authentication middleware
        const user = req.user.id
        const collections= await CollectionModel.find({users: user}) // filtered by user _id
        res.send(collections)
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})
```